# How to convert Ubuntu Server to Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: server, raid, desktop-environments, mdadm

I am considering installing Ubuntu Server to get software RAID (`mdadm`).  I understand that doing so will just get me the command line, with no GUI features.  I also know that I can install the `ubuntu-desktop` package to get all the GUI stuff that I'm used to with the desktop edition.

The problem with that route is that it will leave me with all sorts of server-related stuff installed, like apache and bind, that I don't need.  What's the easiest way to remove those packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tasksel` to install/uninstall most server related packages like Apache, SSH Server, Bind, etc. This is the semi-GUI tool appeared when you was installing Ubuntu Server.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Run it by:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Uncheck every service you don't want.

Comment: is it still valid?